# Powershell uninstall app with custom Wix flag command line arg

Tags: powershell, cmd, uninstallation

I created a custom Wix flag command line argument (FLAG = "remove") to bypass some custom messageboxes during an uninstall. For a windows batch command, the command looks like this:

```
AppInstaller.exe /quiet /uninstall FLAG="remove"
```

I want to convert this command to work in Powershell but am having trouble with the syntax.
I've tried the following:

```
Start-Process ./AppInstaller.exe /s FLAG="remove" -Wait
Start-Process ./ProductivityAppInstaller.exe -ArgumentList /s FLAG="remove" -Wait
```

Powershell doesn't seem to recognize my custom Wix argument. I got the error "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'FLAG=remove'".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea about using `-ArgumentList`. However, you need to enclose the arguments in double quotes and backtick escape any double quote literals that you need to pass to the executable.

```
Start-Process -FilePath "./AppInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "/s FLAG=`"remove`"" -Wait
```

`-ArgumentList` expects a string array to be passed to it. Under the covers, PowerShell joins those array elements by a space (). If you provide the parameter a value that is a single string with the .exe arguments separated by a space, you achieve the same result. Since PowerShell attempts to perform string expansion when it detects a double quote pair, you need to indicate to PowerShell to not do that when it is undesirable. By escaping a double quote, PowerShell will skip the expansion of that escaped double quote.

A slightly alternative approach is to create an array of your arguments. Then pass the array into the `-ArgumentList` parameter. You will still have to include your double quotes literally as part of your string by surrounding argument with single quotes or doing a backtick escape.